# Get unique ID for a running process

Tags: c#, uniqueidentifier

I'm currently looking to replace a system I've previously implemented that generates a unique id that is valid from when the process opens until when it closes, a random unique ID is generated using a mix of system time and other variables each time the application is started.

What I'm looking to do is generate a unique identifier for the process itself, the Process ID isn't something I can use as it's possible that it's reused

Does anyone know of a way to generate a unique id for a single process based on the process itself?

Comment: Could you use a guid? That would most likely be unique.

Comment: Yes, it would, what I need though is something that I can continually generate within the same session that has the same ID, simply based on the Process.

Comment: What about using combining the process PID with the number of ticks picked from datetime.Now ? Or total seconds from epoch, depending of your process creation rate ?

Comment: How these IDs are used?

Comment: @DanHall Why? This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2):

`Process.StartTime.Ticks` can be used an unique identifier because its impossible to run more than a process in a single tick

Comment: Technically it's possible on a multicore CPU

Comment: if we are talking about possibilities then add process id asa a prefix to that uniuq identifier string :)